# social media login in nextjs project

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, next.js, next-auth

I am integrating social media login in nextjs project with nextauth and i am able to get access_token from google in pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js

Here's the code snippet

```
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook"
import LinkedInProvider from "next-auth/providers/linkedin"

const options =  {

  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "consent",
          access_type: "offline",
          response_type: "code"
        }
      }
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID
    }),
    LinkedInProvider({
      clientId: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID_SECRET
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    
    async signIn(account, profile) {
      return true
    },
    async jwt(token) {
      const access_token = token.account.access_token;
      return token;
    }
  },
};
export default NextAuth(options);
```

The problem i am facing is i want to pass acess_token from callback(jwt) function to the client side login page so that i can pass that access_token  to backend api and get access and refresh tokens as the response
so can  anyone help me how to pass access_token from [...nextauth].js to client side page.